# Java Generic subclassing with constructor

Tags: java, class

My situation is

First Class:

```
public class Form{
   public Form(String id){
       super(id); 
   }
  // some methods ...
}
```

Second Class:

```
public class Panel{
  public Panel(String id){
     super(id);
  }
// some methods...
}
```

I can extend both Classes  like

```
public class MyForm extends Form {
```

And

```
public class MyPanel extends Panel {
```

But this is duplicating code because in `MyPanel` and `MyForm` I have one and the same method twice!?

I know that in Java it is not possible to extend from 2 Classes....

I would like to create an abstract generic `Class` that extend from `Form` or `Panel` and inherit a method `findComponent()`.

Comment: How about use an interface to hold `findComponent()` and have `Form` and `Panel` implement it?

Comment: ^^^^ That's the answer

Comment: Yes! But then i must implement it two times anyway in MyPanel and MyForm. I tought an interface is only an instruction what a class has to implement.

Comment: Create a delegate class where you write the code and call that in both... unless it's more troublesome to do so.

Comment: It might be helpful to see the strategy pattern. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern. An example in http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074195/swing-gui-programming/strategy-for-success.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways:

1. you can use an interface and declare the `findComponent()` method
   prototype;
2. you can create an AbstractComponent abstract class which contains your `findComponent()`.

It will depend on what you need exactly. If you have to write your findComponent method only once, use an abstract method. Else, use interface.

For Abstract solution:

```
Form extends AbstractComponent {
   ...
   @Override
   protected void findComponent() {...}


Panel extends AbstractComponent  {
   ...
   @Override
   protected void findComponent() {...}
}

public abstract class AbstractCOmponent {
   protected abstract void findComponent();
}
```

@Giovanni Botta: yes, of course, always prefer Interface. And always prefer composition than inheritance. But here, if he does not want to duplicate its code, Abstract will be better.

Comment: Thank you Ipratlong for your answer!! Yes i know!!!! But the classes  Form and Panel are the Superclasses!!!! I am not able to extend them! 
these superclasses only have to become a (same) method extra!!!

Comment: Yes, but you can do that (I've got a problem with formatting... I write it to you in my answer) :
`Form extends AbstractComponent {
   ...
   @Override
   protected void findComponent() {...}


Panel extends AbstractComponent  {
   ...
   @Override
   protected void findComponent() {...}
}

public abstract class AbstractCOmponent {
   protected abstract void findComponent();
}`

Answer (score 2):

Write a superclass (or interface) for `Form` and `Panel`.

```
public abstract class Item {
   private abstract void duplicateMethod();
}

public class Form extends Item {
   private void duplicateMethod() {

   }
}

public class Panel extends Item {
   private void duplicateMethod() {

   }
}
```

Even better, make `Item` an interface (but that depends on what you use it for).

Answer (score 0):

```
public abstract class ComponetFinder {
    public ComponetFinder(String id){
        // Do stuff with id
    }
    // some methods...
}

public class Form extends ComponetFinder {
    public Form(String id){
        super(id);
    }
    // some methods...
}

public class Panel extends ComponetFinder {
    public Panel(String id){
        super(id);
    }
    // some methods...
}
```

And then you can just use

```
public class MyPanel extends Panel {}
public class MyForm extends Form {}
```

etc

Comment: Thank you all for your comments ....  this is very close .... but i cant extend Form and Panel because this classes are i a Package!!!

Comment: I need something like that:

public class ExtendedComponent<T> {
}

an then  something like:

public class MyPanel extends ExtendedPanel<Form>{
}

or thimething like that ????????? GRR....

Answer (score 0):

I recommend always programming against interfaces. It's the best idiom in java:

```
interface ComponentFinder{
  void findComponent();
}

interface Form extends ComponentFinder{}

interface Panel extends ComponentFinder{}
```

now you can have your classes implement the interfaces. Note that in java 8, interfaces can have [default methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html) which provides greater flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

While Java does not support multiple inheritance, you can do what you want with an interface. (This item 1 of the answer of lpratlong .)

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html for the concept.

If you want both Form and Panel (or MyForm or MyPanel) to implement `findComponent()`, first have an interface class.

```
interface IFormPanel {
   int findComponent();  // your return type is probably not int.
}
```

Then you would change your MyForm and MyPanel declaration:

```
public class MyForm implements IFormPanel {
```

This would make a *contract* promising that MyForm must implement `findComponent()`.

Now if you wanted findComponent to return a component, you should follow one of the other answers and create an abstract superclass. Then it could return a ComponentFinder (in DirkyJerky's example) or an Item (in Anubian Noob's example) instead of an int.